# Java generics type mismatch

Tags: java, generics

I have an abstract class defined as:

```
public abstract class TCV<T extends MF> {
    public Map<String, MVR<T>> operation() {
        ...
    }
}
```

main code:

```
TCV<? extends MF> o = new TCVConcrete();
Map<String, MVR< ? extends MF>> map = o.operation();
```

Error from eclipse:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<String,MVR<capture#5-of ? extends MF>> to Map<String,MVR<? extends MF>>`

**EDIT**

```
public class TCVConcrete extends TCV<MFV2> {
}

public class MFV2 extends MF {
}
```

Comment: Can you post the first few lines of class TCVConcrete ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is because you can't cast `Box<Tiger>` to `Box<Cat>`, why? You can think it as,

A `Box<Cat>` can contain cats and tigers, but a `Box<Tiger>` can contain only tigers. If you cast a `Box<Tiger>` to `Box<Cat>`, and later you throw a `BlackCat` into the `Box<Tiger>`:

```
Box<Cat> catBox = tigerBox;
catBox.throwHere(new BlackCat());
```

and then, the tigerBox is corrupted.

Let me reword your question as:

```
public abstract class Company<T extends Cat> {
    public Box<T> getFavBox() {
        // ...
    }
    public Set<Box<T>> getBoxes() {
        // ...
    }
}

Company<? extends Cat> o = new ETCatCompany();
Box<? extends Cat> boxes = o.getFavBox();        // ok
Set<Box<? extends Cat>> boxes = o.getBoxes();    // error
```

As you see, `o.getFavBox()` will work but `o.getBoxes()` not, why?

Because, you could not throw any concrete Cat into `Box<? extends Cat>`, which may possibly corrupt the unknown box. However, you can throw a `Box<BlackCat>` into `Set<Box<? extends Cat>>`, which may in turns corrupt a `Set<Box<Tiger>>`.

Or, you may think it as:

```
Cat ^ Tiger => Cat
Box<Cat> ^ BigBox<Cat> => Box<Cat>
Box<Cat> ^ Box<Tiger> => Box<? extends Cat>
Box<Cat> ^ BigBox<Tiger>
    => (Box<Cat> ^ BigBox<Cat>) ^ (BigBox<Cat> ^ BigBox<Tiger>)
    => Box<Cat> ^ BigBox<? extends Cat>
    => Box<? extends Cat> ^ BigBox<? extends Cat>
    => Box<? extends Cat>

Set<Box<Cat>> ^ Set<BigBox<Cat>> => Set<? extends Box<Cat>>
Set<Box<Cat>> ^ Set<Box<Tiger>> => Set<? extends Box<? extends Cat>>
Set<Box<Cat>> ^ Set<BigBox<Tiger>> => Set<? extends Box<? extends Cat>>

? extends Cat ^ ? extends Tiger => ? extends Cat
Box<? extends Cat> ^ BigBox<? extends Cat> => Box<? extends Cat>
Box<? extends Cat> ^ Box<? extends Tiger> 
    => ? extends Box<? extends (? extends Cat)>
    => ? extends Box<? extends Cat>

Set<Box<? extends Cat>> ^ Set<BigBox<? extends Cat>> 
    => Set<? extends Box<? extends Cat>>

Set<Box<? extends Cat>> ^ Set<Box<? extends Tiger>>     // You are here.
    => Set<? extends Box<? extends Cat>>

Set<Box<? extends Cat>> ^ Set<BigBox<? extends Tiger>> 
    => Set<? extends Box<? extends Cat>>
```

Or more likely in your case, give several operation() calls:

```
Map<String, MVR<?1 extends MF>> x1 = o.operation();
Map<String, MVR<?2 extends MF>> x2 = o.operation();
...
Map<String, MVR<?n extends MF>> x2 = o.operation();
```

Then, what's the common type of all?

```
x1 ^ x2 ^ ... ^ xn
    => Map<String, MVR<?1 extends MF>> ^ Map<String, MVR<?2 extends MF>> ^ ...
    => Map<String, ? extends MVR<? extends MF>> ^ ...
    ...
    => Map<String, ? extends MVR<? extends MF>>
```

Well, it's definitely nothing wrong with two wildcards, it's about mathematical induction...

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you have two different generic definitions that *could* be the same:

```
TCV<? extends MF> o = new TCVConcrete();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Map<String, MVR< ? extends MF>> map = o.operation();
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

While these two could point to the same type, they could also point to two different sub-types of MF. The compiler doesn't like that.

You can solve that with a type variable in a dedicated method.
This should work:

```
public void <T extends MF> doSomething(){
    TCV<T> o = new TCVConcrete();
    Map<String, MVR<T>> map = o.operation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way for the generics system to understand that the indicated generic types in the two lines (when applied to a concrete implementation) actually refer to the same concrete type when the compiler does its business.

```
TCV<? extends MF> o = new TCVConcrete();
Map<String, MVR< ? extends MF>> map = o.operation();
```

In the simple case of `Serializable`, there are many classes implementing `Serializable`, so one statement could mean one class, and another statement could mean another, thus this will not compile. You need to create a type scope at the top of the file, and then use the same type for both lines, or implement a subclass of MF and use this for both lines, rather than leaving it as a floating generic type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using two ? wildcards, which basically say "MF or some unspecified subclass of MF". But that could mean two *different* subclasses of MF; and that's why the types for the assignment don't match.

What you probably want is not to use the wildcards at all. This should work:

```
TCV<MF> o = new TCVConcrete();
Map<String, MVR<MF>> map = o.operation();
```